# Error retreiving database name wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash

I was trying the below code to retrieve database name from wordpress configuration file. But somehow a single inverted comma at the beginning is causing trouble.

```
db=`grep DB_NAME /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-config.php | tr -d "(',);" | cut -d" " -f2`;
echo $db;
mysqldump -uadmin -p$(cat > /etc/psa.psa.shadow) $db > $db.sql
```

As given below it shows the output without any special characters but the below error shows an issue.

```
laysalaysa_laysalaysa

'" when selecting the databasencorrect database name 'laysalaysa_laysalaysa'
```

Comment: Are you sure that laysalaysa_laysalaysa is the database name in mysql?

Comment: got it working , there was a '\r' (carriage return). truncated it using tr ang everything working again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

carriage return (\r) caused the issue. Truncated it and script worked. But could not identify what cause the same.